# Cannot transfer files to cell after enabling USB debugging

Tags: motorola-moto-e4

I enabled USB debugging now I can't transfer any file to my cell after this.
I tried disabling it but once I disable and close settings it enables itself again automatically.

I connected my cell with USB port to my PC and it shows the message that it's connect and even the icon but if I open the icon to transfer file by copying or cutting , I don't see any desirable file in my cell in which I have to place the file.
What to do now?

Help me on disabling USB debugging please.
Also help me on transferring files during USB debugging enabled and disabled both.

Cell: Moto E4

Comment: You need to either enable MTP or PTP to be able to transfert files. Otherwise you'll need to use ADB to push files

Comment: I am tapping on MTP and PTP as well but nothing happens ever since I enabled USB debugging.

Comment: Try this: open the dialer then dial *#0808#, this will open a menu then select MTP+ADB

Comment: Okay so I tried this and an incomplete message pops up after I dial this whichh says "Service is curre" just this.
However, now I'm able to transfer files though. Don't know how this happened but thanks.
Anyway can you also help me on disabling USB debugging? It's still pops up everytime I connect my cell to PC.

Comment: Go to developers option in settings

Comment: I already did that but it came again turned itself on but anyway I just factory reset my cell so no worries anyway.